# mysqli_fetch_assoc doesnt return first row

Tags: php

sorry I am very new to PHP. This has probably been asked before but I am unable to get this code working, I am currently trying to check whether a user has logged in before but the mysqli_fetch_assoc only seems to pull through the second row, this query should only return one row so i only figured it out it was returning two when i added a duplicate to my DB. I have found similar questions and solutions but havent been able to figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

```
require_once 'login.php';
$db_server = mysqli_connect($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password,$db_database);
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'ben944' AND firstlogin = '0'";
$result = mysqli_query($db_server,$query);

        if(!$result) {
            echo "not working";
            exit;
        }

        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: Is this from a tutorial?  I see this way to often and it is inconceivable that so many people would do this for no reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The separate `$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);` line already fetches and removes the first row from the result before the while loop starts. That's why it's not printed by the while loop (which you have added for debugging purposes obviously).

Comment: As OP is very new, an explanation would be great as well

Comment: Thanks Erki! This has helped a lot.

Comment: thanks Erki! you saved my one week confusing moments :D